# upload no obtiene el nombre del la imagen

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tratando de hacer el prosedimiento de upload una imagen en laravel:

1)Trato guardar el nombre de una imagen en mi tabla SQL 
2)Guardar la imagen en una carpeta

pero actual mente se esta guardando un nombre : `C:\xampp\tmp\php1AF8.tmp` el cual no es la ruta, ni el nombre de la imagen, y la imagen se esta guardando correctamente en carpeta `pulic` bajo el nombre de carpeta `logos` (\public\storage\logos\fileToUpload1559322149) mi codigo es el siguiente:

/resources/views/ClientesCreate.Blade.php
Formulario

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('clientesStore') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf

<div>
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload"  aria-describedby="fileHelp">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" name="nombre"/>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="correo"/>
</div>

<button href="">Nuevo Cliente</button>
</form>
```

/routes/web.php
Ruta

```
Route::get ('/contactosStore', 'HomeController@contactosStore')->name('contactosStore');
Route::post('/contactosStore', 'HomeController@contactosStore')->name('contactosStore');
```

\app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php
Controlador

```
use App\Clientes;
class HomeController extends Controller
{

//Clientes store
    public function clientesStore(Request $request)
    {
    $fileToUpload = "fileToUpload".time().'.'.request()->fileToUpload->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->validate(['fileToUpload' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:1024',]);
    $request->fileToUpload->storeAs('logos',$fileToUpload);   

    $validatedData = $request->validate([ 
         'nombre' => 'required|max:255',
         'correo' => 'required|max:255',
         $fileToUpload => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:1024',
     ]);

$Clientes = Clientes::create($validatedData);
     return redirect('/clientes')->with('success','se creeo el cliente correctamente.');
    }
```

\app\Clientes.php
Modelo

```
class Clientes extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'idCliente';
    protected $fillable = ['idCliente',
                           'nombre',
                           'correo', 
                           'fileToUpload'];
}
```

\config\filesystem.php
la configuracion en config para documentos (solo cambie esta linea)

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),
```

mi resultado base de datos clientes.sql

```
id nombre correo fileToUpload
23 /cliente 17 /cliente17@cliente17.com / C:\xampp\tmp\php1AF8.tmp
```

si la imagen se esta guardando ajo nombres como este : fileToUpload1559322149.jpg, siendo que el nombre original es img.jpg me gustaria guardar en mi tabla el nombre fileToUpload1559322149.jpg para poder mostrarlo despues en una tabla

*Nota: trate de ser lo mas explisito posible y mostrar la informacion por si alguien tiene el problema de las imagenes y le es util ver el camino completo, siempre a sido un tema recurrente*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es que estás queriendo guardar el objeto Clientes directamente con los datos validados.

Primero valida los datos. Nota que estas validando 'fileToUpload'como un archivo de ciertos mimes types.

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([ 
        'nombre' => 'required|max:255',
        'correo' => 'required|max:255',
        'fileToUpload' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:1024',
]);
```

Luego crea un nombre nuevo para el archivo.

```
$fileName = "fileToUpload".time().'.'.$request->file('fileToUpload')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Luego guarda el archivo en el disco por defecto ('public' en este caso), la carpeta 'logos' y con el nombre que acabas de generar.

```
$request->file('fileToUpload')->storeAs('logos', $fileName);
```

Para guardar en base de datos, debes pasarle el nuevo nombre que has creado.
Puedes reemplazar el dato en el array de los datos validados (no me agrada porque el código no se explica a sí mismo):

```
$validatedData['fileToUpload'] = $fileName;
Clientes::create($validatedData);
```

O creando un array con los datos a guardar:

```
$data = [
    'nombre' => $request->nombre,
    'correo' => $request->correo,
    'fileToUpload' => $fileName
];
Clientes::create($data);

return redirect('/clientes')->with('success','se creeo el cliente correctamente.');
```

Comment: muchas gracias ! incluso el tip de array , espero que esto le ayude a alguien que este en el problema de update images como yo (como nota use el comando en consola >php asrtisan storage:link por el asunto de los links. una ves mas te estoy enorme...gigante mente agradecido :')

Comment: genial! asumí que tenías resuelta la parte del disco y los links porque sólo mencionas lo de guardar en BD.  También aprendo y me entero de cosas viendo las preguntas que se hacen aquí. Saludos